# Subtract from each cell in pandas dataframe based on value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this-- it's a dataframe and all values are floats:

```
data=np.random.randint(3000,size=(10,1))
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

For each value, if it's between 570 and 1140, I want to subtract 570.
If it's over 1140, I want to subtract 1140 from the value. I wrote this function to do that.

```
 def AdjustTimes(val):
         if val > 570 and val < 1140:
             val = val-570
         elif val > 1140:
             val = val - 1140
```

Based on another question I tried to apply it using `data.applymap(AdjustTimes)`. I got no error but the function does not seem to have been applied.

Comment: You should seed your data, so the output is deterministic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setup**

```
data

      0
0  1863
1  2490
2  2650
3  2321
4   822
5    82
6  2192
7   722
8  2537
9   874
```

First, let's create masks for each of your conditions. One pandaic approach is using `between` to retrieve a mask for the first condition -

```
m1 = data.loc[:, 0].between(570, 1140, inclusive=True)
```

Or, you can do this with a couple of logical operators -

```
m1 = data.loc[:, 0].ge(570) & data.loc[:, 0].le(1140)
```

And,

```
m2 = data.loc[:, 0].gt(1140)
```

Now, to perform replacement, you have a couple of options.

**Option 1**
Use `loc` to index and subtract -

```
data.loc[m1, 0] -= 570
data.loc[m2, 0] -= 1140
```

```
data

      0
0   723
1  1350
2  1510
3  1181
4   252
5    82
6  1052
7   152
8  1397
9   304
```

Equivalent version for a `pd.Series` -

> ```
> m1 = data.ge(570) & data.le(1140)
> m2 = data.gt(1140)
>
> data.loc[m1] -= 570
> data.loc[m2] -= 1140
> ```

---

**Option 2**
You can also do this with `np.where` (but it'd be a bit more inefficient).

```
v = data.loc[:, 0]
data.loc[:, 0] = np.where(m1, v - 570, np.where(m2, v - 1140, v))
```

Here, `m1` and `m2` are the masks computed from before.

```
data

      0
0   723
1  1350
2  1510
3  1181
4   252
5    82
6  1052
7   152
8  1397
9   304
```

Equivalent `pd.Series` code -

> ```
> data[:] = np.where(m1, data - 570, np.where(m2, data - 1140, data))
> ```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_encoding_stimtimes.py", line 93, in <module>
    m1 = data.loc[:, 0].ge(570) & data.loc[:, 0].le(1140)
....
line 126, in _has_valid_tuple
    raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers

I got this error when I tried each of the 2 ways in option 1

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like:

```
data=np.random.randint(3000,size=(10,1))
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
data = data -570*((data > 570) & (data < 1140)) -1140*(data > 1140)
```

Comment: I get a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' even though I have the line data.astype(float) so my data should be float

Comment: may be python version differences? not sure..i was using 3.6

Answer (score 0):

The applymap method is designed to generate a new dataframe, not to modify an existing one (and the function it calls should return a value for the new cell rather than modifying its argument). You don't show the line where you actually use applymap, but I suspect it's just `data.applymap(AdjustTimes)` on its own. If you change your code to the following it should work fine:

```
def AdjustTimes(val):
    if val >= 1140:
        return val - 1140
    elif val >= 570: 
        return val - 570

data = data.applymap(AdjustTimes)
```

(I've also cleaned up the `if` statements to be a little faster and deal with the case where Val = 1140 (your original code wouldn't adjust that one).